# What is an easy way to export thousands of Adobe Bridge thumbnails for a remote collaborator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, workflow, batch-processing

Using Adobe Bridge and/or other Creative Cloud software, how can I export thumbnails with filenames, for a remote collaborator?

I realize there is a tedious way to do this. I am asking for an efficient way to do this. For example, can I export the cache database and have the other party import it?

I have about 60,000 NEF (Nikon RAW) and MOS (Leaf RAW) image files organized into folders and subfolders. Exporting them manually will take an inordinately long time. I need my collaborator to be able to look through all of these and specify file names that they choose.

Comment: I believe you need to resign to the fact that you will need to export small size JPEG files. I may be wrong but I have not heard any way to share your cache and it be visible on another computer. They are linked to the image files in the database. Selecting the files in the cache may be a different kind of tedious work, I am not even sure if they are kept in a parallel order to the actual files.

Comment: Hey A K. Are you looking to share the folder, make a website for it, or a catalog (PDF)?